# Conversion from INT to varchar in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where there are values like 20170730 and also 0 values are there which is INT type

I am trying to convert it to value like 30/07/2017, for which i am using the below code,

```
Select convert(NVARCHAR(10),convert(date,convert(NCHAR(8),datecolumn)),103) from table
```

But for the zero values i am getting the below error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
If i delete all the zero this working fine but problem having with zero.

My requirement is to convert when there a date value and if 0 are there then it should be zero only like  below,

```
Result 
30/07/2017
0
```

Can u pls help

Comment: [`Try_Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: How about `select case when datecolumn = 0 then '0' else convert(...) end`

Comment: Why not convert it to a date and time value and leave it as one, as that appears to clearly be what it is.

Comment: @AlexK. Its working fine..

Comment: Storing dates using anything other than a date type is a *serious* bug. What's going to prevent someone from storing 5? Or 22222222? What does 20200407 mean? April 7th or July 4th? Using "magic" values to represent missing data is a bad idea too. What does 0 mean?  In the case, the correct type is `date`. Missing values are represented by NULL - no value at all.

Comment: @SandipDas fix the bad design and you won't have to parse magic values, lose indexing or have to rebuild every date function

Comment: @habo I am not sure about Try_convert trying to search in google... if I can do this in that way because although case one is simple but with huge data it will take more time to search whether its a zero then do the operation. I mean with crores of data

Comment: @SandipDas `with huge data it will take more time` that's why this is such a bad design. You can't use any index on that column because you have to convert it to something else before use. Besides, `CONVERT` is no different than `TRY_CONVERT`. The only thing that changes is the return value in case of error

Comment: I know @PanagiotisK :) but its the existing architecture I cant change, I have to query from that and fetch data only.. thanks

Comment: with 3 converts in there, you might be better off doing CONCAT + SUBSTRING instead.

Comment: @SandipDas in such situation there are two cases. Either a) you lost, and probably nobody in the company knows anything about databases or b) you're missing something. Such date-as-number fields are used in Calendar or Date dimension tables in *really old* databases, before `date` was introduced. With such tables though, string representations, date parts like months, weeks, quarters etc are available as extra, indexed fields. There shouldn't be any need to convert the date key to anything else, just read the already formatted value.

Comment: @SandipDas if you have a calendar table and need a new display format, the answer is to add the extra field to the table, *not* parse every row in a 1Bn row fact table trying to parse the DateDim key. Adding the extra format will only have to calculate a few thousand values just once. After that it's just a trivial lookup

Comment: @Panagiotis, you are right as because there are multiple applications involved with the database and all the data are storing from downstream may be thats why they kept it like that... Not sure about the background but I will definitely propose this

Comment: can you help to on this also, if that fine

Comment: I have varchar value like 1213141, and I want convert it like 12:13:14:1 ..any suggestion please

Comment: @SandipDas if there's no Calendar or Date dimension, it's easy to create one. If you search for `SQL Server Calendar Table` you'll find a lot of scripts, [like this one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). You can use methods like `FORMAT` with custom format strings to add extra fields in various formats,  or fields with period values like `YYYY-MM`, and use. Typically, `FORMAT` is slow but in this case it's only going to run once.

Comment: What is `12:13:14:1` ? What's that `1` at the end? 12 hours 12 minutes 14 seconds and what? 1 ms? 100 ms?

Comment: @panagiotisK , this is existing varchar value in table and in the select output I have to show this like XX:XX:XX:X and the varchar value in table is of varchar(7) .. I hope this is time value they want

Comment: @SandipDas Re: `1213141` ask a new question in ... _a new question_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, you can try to use a `CASE` expression

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN nmuloc = 0 THEN
           '0'
         ELSE
           convert(varchar(10),
                   convert(date,
                           convert(varchar(8),
                                   nmuloc),
                           112),
                   103)
       END
       FROM elbat;
```

or `try_convert()` and `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT coalesce(convert(varchar(10),
                        try_convert(date,
                                    convert(varchar(8),
                                            nmuloc),
                                    112),
                       103),
                '0')
       FROM elbat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ea5829c5305881cc75175671845749fe)

The latter one will also correct other "malformed" data like `123` for example. The former will also fail in such cases. You may want that or not.

But, as also already pointed out in the comments, your real problem is that you use an inappropriate data type. Change the column's datatype to some [date/time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15) to **really** fix this.

Comment: The second one is more accurate. thanks so much I tested it

Comment: Can you suggest on the other one please, how to append and make a 7 digit varchar value to something like XX:XX:XX:X . I mean 1110100 to 11:10:10:0

Comment: @SandipDas: One question per thread please. Open another question (as in post), if you have another question.

Comment: sure, i will do that.